# Get combined Partial documents from envelope

Tags: docusignapi

If I have 3 documents in an envelope. Can I get only 1st and 2nd document as Combined one single pdf document by using docusign API.

I understand envelopesApi.GetDocument gives either one document or combined of all the documents in an envelope. But I need to combine only 1st and 2nd document and fetch it.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only get all of the docs combined or none. You can't pick and choose.

I suggest that you download the docs separately and then assemble the ones that you want into a final PDF Portfolio.

It is very important that you don't simply merge the individual PDF files together since each one is digitally signed (the merge process would break the digital signatures).

Instead, create a PDF Portfolio of the documents. [Software libraries](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=PDF%20Portfolio%20library) are available to help you.

Comment: Thanks. will try that